# SSO architecture/gems for Rails SaaS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on

I am looking for advice on which tools (gems, or third party IDaaS) I should use to implement the following:
- I have a rails app SaaS app (using devise and cancan)
- Some clients will want to use SSO so their employees who are using our app do not have to create accounts.  For these users we would like to capture their email address or some information so we can send emails to them
- Other clients will not be sophisticated enough and will rely on us to generate user accounts for them (which we already have in place and would like to continue using)

So the question is: What is the simplest/most efficient set of gems/tools i should consider for this